# How to dynamically change the margin of a widget when the width of a window/device changes in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, web, responsive-design

I want to increase the margin of a container widget when the width of the window of the browser increases. How can I achieve that?
I tried using MediaQuery class and other responsive UI packages but the margin and padding amount remained the same

Comment: did you try `LayoutBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MediaQuery` and making the margin by percentage as browser width increases.

```
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size * 0.20) // 20% of the browserSize = padding
```

Answer (score 0):

try `LayoutBuilder`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlexibleMargin extends StatelessWidget {
  const FlexibleMargin({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => Center(
          ///this yellowAccent is showing margin area
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellowAccent,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.pinkAccent,

              ///margin 4x for better view
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(
                (constraints.maxWidth * .02) * 4,
              ),
              // padding: EdgeInsets.all(
              //   (constraints.maxWidth * .02) * 2,
              // ),
              child: Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight * .6,
                width: constraints.maxWidth * .6,
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted to achieve but the LayoutBuilder definitely helped a lot. Thank You !

Comment: My reputation is less than 15 